# Options binding not populating data in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a html page along with knockout JavaScript and try to populate some data over the drop down list using the following script

**HTML**

```
    <td>
        <select data-bind="options:transactionType,optionsText:'typeOfTransaction', value:selectedType,optionsCaption:'Type'">
        </select>
    </td>
    @section scripts {
    <script src="~/App/transactionType.js"></script>
   }
```

**Knockout Js**

```
var Type = function (name) {
        this.typeOfTransaction = name;

    };

var viewModel = {
    transactionType: ko.observableArray([
        new Type("Buy"),
        new Type("Sell"),
        new Type("None")
    ]),
    selectedType: ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

But when I run the script it threw me an exception

```
uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: transactionType is not defined;
Bindings value: options:transactionType,optionsText:'typeOfTransaction', value:selectedType,optionsCaption:'Type'
```

**Is there a better way I can fix this?**

Comment: Show your `ko.applyBindings()` call.

Comment: I have edited the question adding ko.applyBindings(viewModel) at the end of knockout

Comment: working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/21284/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following markup:

```
 <td>
        <select data-bind="options:$root.transactionType,optionsText:'typeOfTransaction',optionsValue:'typeOfTransaction', value:$root.selectedType,optionsCaption:'Type'">
        </select>
    </td>
```

May be your `select` binding is inside another binding like a `foreach` binding because of you have to explicitly mention `$root` so that the binding searches the observable in root definitions of the view model. Also you have to mention `optionsValue` binding also in a`select` element bindings.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it didn't work and more over I have another knockout view model I referenced in the same html script

Comment: You cannot use multiple view models on the same element. What exactly are you doing in the other view model?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that and fixed it